# How do I save the character under the point in emacs

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a list of special unicode characters that I use frequently in one of my files.
To avoid typing (and learning) unicode numbers all the time I would like to just have a line with those characters at the top of my file (it's only 25 symbols) and save/yank them when I need them.

I cannot find the proper shortcut to save the character under the point though...

Comment: If applicable, you may prefer to use an existing input method, as they are brilliant for making character composition easy. For an example, see `M-x describe-input-method RET latin-4-postfix RET`. For details on using the mechanism, see `C-h i g (emacs) Select Input Method RET`. I would also take a look at http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CategoryInternationalization

Comment: Another tip: map those 25 characters of yours behind `C-x 8`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's no different to copying anything else. Move point to the character you wish to copy, set the mark with <kbd>C-SPC</kbd>, move forward one character so that the region covers the character of interest, and save to the kill ring with <kbd>M-w</kbd>.

Or you could do something like this:

```el
(defun my-copy-character-as-kill (pos)
  "Copy the character at point (or POS) to the kill ring."
  (interactive "d")
  (if (eobp)
      (error "End of buffer.")
    (copy-region-as-kill pos (1+ pos))
    (when (called-interactively-p 'interactive)
      (let ((print-escape-newlines t))
        (message "%S" (char-to-string (char-after pos)))))))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c c") 'my-copy-character-as-kill)
```

Comment: Of course this works perfectly although I am still a little surprised that this is not predefined... 
But I guess for anything more than just a handful of characters the input methods would be the way to go anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to go, especially if don't use a lot of such characters and don't want to fiddle with an input method.

Download library [`ucs-cmds.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/ucs-cmds.el) and put it in your `load-path` (byte-compile it). Then put this in your init file (~/.emacs):

```
(require 'ucs-cmds)
(define-key global-map [remap insert-char] 'ucsc-insert)
```

Then use `M-- C-x 8 RET` and use completion to enter the Unicode name or code point of the character you want.  That does two things: `C-x 8 RET` inserts the character you chose before the cursor.  The `M--` makes it also create a command with the same name as the character.  You can then bind that command to a handy key sequence.  For example:

```
M-- C-x 8 RET greek small letter lambda RET
```

That defines command `greek-small-letter-lambda`, which you can bind to some key sequence.

If you want to define such commands for several Unicode characters at once, you can instead just use macro `ucsc-make-commands` to do so.  See the Commentary in file `ucs-cmds.el`.  You provide a regexp to the macro.  It is matched against all Unicode character names.  An insertion command is created for each of the characters whose name matches.

Sample command creations:

```
 (ucsc-make-commands "^math") ; Math symbols
 (ucsc-make-commands "latin") ; Latin alphabet characters
 (ucsc-make-commands "arabic")
 (ucsc-make-commands "^cjk")  ; Chinese, Japanese, Korean characters
 (ucsc-make-commands "^box drawings ")
 (ucsc-make-commands "^greek [a-z]+ letter") ; Greek characters
 (ucsc-make-commands "\\(^hangul\\|^circled hangul\\|^parenthesized hangul\\)")
```